# Historische Zeitschrift Bibliography Repeated Author Names

Tags: biblatex

I am using slightly customised `Historische Zeitschrift Style`. When I typeset my file in the literature list at the end some of the author names are repeating (all though they shouldn't). Here is how this looks like:

[image]

The things marked with red shouldn't be there. I presume that has something to do with the customisations of the package I have.

Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks,
     citecolor=black,
     filecolor=black,
     linkcolor=black,
     urlcolor=black
}
\usepackage{chngcntr}
\counterwithin*{footnote}{section}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib} 
@incollection{athanasius1998,
    Address = {Berlin/New York},
    Author = {{Athanasius Alexandrinus}},
    Booktitle = {Athanasius Werke - Die dogmatischen Schriften},
    Call-Number = {TH: Vb 17.02-1.1.2},
    Date-Added = {2010-10-16 13:24:30 +0200},
    Date-Modified = {2014-03-13 17:12:32 +0000},
    Editor = {Marin Tetz and others},
    Keywords = {source},
    Pages = {109-175},
    Publisher = {Walter de Gruyter},
    Read = {No},
    Series = {Urkunden zur Geschichte des Arianischen Streites 318-328},
    Shortauthor = {Ath.},
    Shorttitle = {Ar. 1},
    Usera = {SCh},
    Title = {Oratio I contra Arianos},
    Volume = {1, Tl. 1, Lfg. 2},
    Year = {1998}}
@incollection{evagrius2011,
    Address = {Paris},
    Author = {{Evagrius Scholasticus}},
    Booktitle = {{\'E}vagre Le Scholastique: Histoire Eccl{\'e}siastique - Livres I-III},
    Call-Number = {TH: Va1.05/542},
    Date-Added = {2013-08-24 12:11:20 +0000},
    Date-Modified = {2014-03-30 11:54:31 +0000},
    Editor = {Joseph Bidez and Leon Parmentier},
    Keywords = {source},
    Publisher = {Les {\'E}ditions du Cerf},
    Series = {Sources chr{\'e}tiennes},
    Shortauthor = {Evagr.},
    Shorttitle = {h.e.},
    Title = {Historia ecclesiastica},
    Usera = {SCh},
    Volume = {542},
    Year = {2011}}
@incollection{gregoire1978,
    Address = {Paris},
    Author = {{Gregorius Nazianzenus}},
    Booktitle = {Discours 27-31},
    Call-Number = {TH: Va 1.05 250},
    Date-Added = {2011-08-29 09:18:38 +0200},
    Date-Modified = {2014-05-29 10:45:06 +0000},
    Editor = {Paul Gallay},
    Keywords = {source},
    Pages = {226-275},
    Publisher = {Les {\'E}ditions du Cerf},
    Series = {Sources chr{\'e}tiennes},
    Shortauthor = {{Gr. Naz.}},
    Shorttitle = {or. 30},
    Title = {Oratio 30: De Filio (Theologica Quatra)},
    Usera = {SCh},
    Volume = {250},
    Year = {1978}}
@incollection{gregoire1974,
    Address = {Paris},
    Author = {{Gregorius Nazianzenus}},
    Booktitle = {Lettres th{\'e}ologiques},
    Call-Number = {TH: Va 1.05 208},
    Date-Added = {2010-04-22 16:22:42 +0200},
    Date-Modified = {2014-03-30 11:54:28 +0000},
    Editor = {Paul Gallay},
    Keywords = {source},
    Pages = {87-95},
    Publisher = {Les {\'E}ditions du Cerf},
    Series = {Sources chr{\'e}tiennes},
    Shortauthor = {{Gr. Naz.}},
    Shorttitle = {ep. 202},
    Title = {Epistula 202: Ad Nectarium Constantinopolitanum},
    Usera = {SCh},
    Volume = {208},
    Year = {1974}}
@incollection{gregorius1981,
    Address = {Paris},
    Author = {{Gregorius Nazianzenus}},
    Booktitle = {Discours 24-26},
    Date-Added = {2014-05-29 12:04:21 +0000},
    Date-Modified = {2014-05-29 12:05:35 +0000},
    Editor = {Justin Mossay},
    Keywords = {source},
    Pages = {40-85},
    Publisher = {Les {\'E}ditions du Cerf},
    Series = {Sources chr{\'e}tiennes},
    Shortauthor = {{Gr. Naz.}},
    Shorttitle = {or. 24},
    Title = {Oratio 24: In laudem s. Cypriani},
    Usera = {SCh},
    Volume = {284},
    Year = {1980}}
@incollection{gregorius1990,
    Address = {Paris},
    Author = {{Gregorius Nazianzenus}},
    Booktitle = {Discours 38-41},
    Date-Added = {2014-03-27 09:58:33 +0000},
    Date-Modified = {2014-03-30 11:53:58 +0000},
    Editor = {Claudio Moreschini},
    Keywords = {source},
    Pages = {104-148},
    Publisher = {Les {\'E}ditions du Cerf},
    Series = {Sources chr{\'e}tiennes},
    Shortauthor = {{Gr. Naz.}},
    Shorttitle = {or. 38},
    Title = {Oratio 38: In Theophania},
    Usera = {SCh},
    Volume = {358},
    Year = {1990}}
@incollection{gregorius1979/1,
    Address = {Paris},
    Author = {{Gregorius Nazianzenus}},
    Booktitle = {Discours 27-31},
    Date-Added = {2014-03-27 09:54:29 +0000},
    Date-Modified = {2014-03-30 18:41:48 +0000},
    Editor = {Paul Gallay},
    Keywords = {source},
    Pages = {176-225},
    Publisher = {Les {\'E}ditions du Cerf},
    Series = {Sources chr{\'e}tiennes},
    Shortauthor = {{Gr. Naz.}},
    Shorttitle = {or. 29},
    Title = {Oratio 29: Theologica III},
    Usera = {SCh},
    Volume = {250},
    Year = {1979}}

@incollection{gregoire1978/2,
    Address = {Paris},
    Author = {{Gregorius Nazianzenus}},
    Booktitle = {Discours 27-31},
    Call-Number = {TH: Va 1.05 250},
    Date-Added = {2014-03-26 18:56:20 +0000},
    Date-Modified = {2014-03-30 11:54:18 +0000},
    Editor = {Paul Gallay},
    Keywords = {source},
    Pages = {276-343},
    Publisher = {Les {\'E}ditions du Cerf},
    Series = {Sources chr{\'e}tiennes},
    Shortauthor = {{Gr. Naz.}},
    Shorttitle = {or. 31},
    Title = {Oratio 31: Theologica V},
    Usera = {SCh},
    Volume = {250},
    Year = {1978}}

@incollection{gregorius1978,
    Address = {Paris},
    Author = {{Gregorius Nazianzenus}},
    Booktitle = {Discours 1-3},
    Date-Added = {2014-03-26 18:48:54 +0000},
    Date-Modified = {2014-03-30 18:42:08 +0000},
    Keywords = {source},
    Pages = {84-241},
    Publisher = {Les {\'E}ditions du Cerf},
    Series = {Sources chr{\'e}tiennes},
    Shortauthor = {{Gr. Naz.}},
    Shorttitle = {or. 2},
    Title = {Oratio 2: Apologetica},
    Usera = {SCh},
    Volume = {247},
    Year = {1978}}

@incollection{gregorius1990/2,
    Address = {Paris},
    Author = {{Gregorius Nazianzenus}},
    Booktitle = {Discours 38-41},
    Date-Added = {2014-03-26 17:58:16 +0000},
    Date-Modified = {2014-03-30 11:53:48 +0000},
    Editor = {Claudio Moreschini},
    Keywords = {source},
    Pages = {150-197},
    Publisher = {Les {\'E}ditions du Cerf},
    Series = {Sources chr{\'e}tiennes},
    Shortauthor = {{Gr. Naz.}},
    Shorttitle = {or. 39},
    Title = {Oratio 39: In sancta lumina},
    Usera = {SCh},
    Volume = {358},
    Year = {1990}}

@incollection{gregorius1992,
    Address = {Paris},
    Author = {{Gregorius Nazianzenus}},
    Booktitle = {Discours 42-43},
    Date-Added = {2014-03-26 17:58:15 +0000},
    Date-Modified = {2014-03-30 11:53:44 +0000},
    Editor = {Jean Bernardi},
    Keywords = {source},
    Pages = {48-115},
    Publisher = {Les {\'E}ditions du Cerf},
    Series = {Sources chr{\'e}tiennes},
    Shortauthor = {{Gr. Naz.}},
    Shorttitle = {or. 42},
    Title = {Oratio 42: Supremum vale},
    Usera = {SCh},
    Volume = {384},
    Year = {1992}}

@incollection{gregorius1990/1,
    Address = {Paris},
    Author = {{Gregorius Nazianzenus}},
    Booktitle = {Discours 38-41},
    Date-Added = {2014-03-26 17:58:15 +0000},
    Date-Modified = {2014-03-30 18:41:25 +0000},
    Editor = {Claudio Moreschini},
    Keywords = {source},
    Pages = {198-311},
    Publisher = {Les {\'E}ditions du Cerf},
    Series = {Sources chr{\'e}tiennes},
    Shortauthor = {{Gr. Naz.}},
    Shorttitle = {or. 40},
    Title = {Oratio 40: In sanctum baptisma},
    Usera = {SCh},
    Volume = {358},
    Year = {1990}}

@incollection{gregorius1980/1,
    Address = {Paris},
    Author = {{Gregorius Nazianzenus}},
    Booktitle = {Discours 20-23},
    Date-Added = {2014-03-26 17:42:35 +0000},
    Date-Modified = {2014-03-30 11:54:01 +0000},
    Editor = {Justin Mossay},
    Keywords = {source},
    Pages = {220-258},
    Publisher = {Les {\'E}ditions du Cerf},
    Series = {Sources chr{\'e}tiennes},
    Shortauthor = {{Gr. Naz.}},
    Shorttitle = {or. 22},
    Title = {Oratio 22: De pace II},
    Usera = {SCh},
    Volume = {270},
    Year = {1980}}

@incollection{gregorius1978/1,
    Address = {Paris},
    Author = {{Gregorius Nazianzenus}},
    Booktitle = {Discours 1-3},
    Date-Added = {2014-03-26 17:42:34 +0000},
    Date-Modified = {2014-03-30 18:41:59 +0000},
    Keywords = {source},
    Pages = {241-255},
    Publisher = {Les {\'E}ditions du Cerf},
    Series = {Sources chr{\'e}tiennes},
    Shortauthor = {{Gr. Naz.}},
    Shorttitle = {or. 3},
    Title = {Oratio 3: Ad eos qui ipsum acciverant nec occurrerant},
    Usera = {SCh},
    Volume = {247},
    Year = {1978}}

@book{moreschini1997,
    Address = {Oxford},
    Author = {{Gregorius Nazianzenus}},
    Call-Number = {Googlebooks},
    Date-Added = {2014-03-26 15:07:53 +0000},
    Date-Modified = {2014-03-26 15:14:45 +0000},
    Editor = {Claudio Moreschini and},
    Keywords = {source},
    Publisher = {Clarendon Press},
    Series = {Oxford Theological Monographs},
    Title = {St. Gregory of Nazianzus: \textit{Poemata Arcana}},
    Translator = {Donald Sykes},
    Year = {1997}}

@book{white1996,
    Address = {Cambridge},
    Author = {{Gregorius Nazianzenus}},
    Call-Number = {Googlebooks},
    Date-Added = {2014-03-26 15:05:53 +0000},
    Date-Modified = {2014-03-26 15:07:22 +0000},
    Editor = {Carolinne White},
    Keywords = {source},
    Publisher = {Cambridge University Press},
    Title = {Gregory of Nazianzus: Autobiographical Poems},
    Translator = {Carolline White},
    Year = {1996}}
@book{gregorius1862,
    Address = {Parisiis},
    Author = {{Gregorius Nazianzenus}},
    Call-Number = {PDF},
    Date-Added = {2014-03-15 15:58:32 +0000},
    Date-Modified = {2014-03-31 08:01:30 +0000},
    Editor = {Jacques Paul Migne},
    Keywords = {source},
    Publisher = {Accurante J.-P. Migne},
    Series = {Patrologiae cursus completus: Series Graeca},
    Shortauthor = {{Gr. Naz.}},
    Shorttitle = {hym. 30},
    Title = {Hymnus 30: Ad Deum},
    Usera = {PG},
    Volume = {37},
    Year = {1862}}
@incollection{gregorius1980,
    Address = {Paris},
    Author = {{Gregorius Nazianzenus}},
    Booktitle = {Discours 20-23},
    Date-Added = {2013-04-25 14:10:40 +0000},
    Date-Modified = {2014-03-30 11:54:04 +0000},
    Editor = {Justin Mossay},
    Keywords = {source},
    Pages = {110-193},
    Publisher = {Les {\'E}ditions du Cerf},
    Series = {Sources chr{\'e}tiennes},
    Shortauthor = {{Gr. Naz.}},
    Shorttitle = {or. 21},
    Title = {Oratio 21: In laudem Athanasii},
    Usera = {SCh},
    Volume = {270},
    Year = {1980}}
@incollection{gregoire1974/2,
    Address = {Paris},
    Author = {{Gregorius Nazianzenus}},
    Booktitle = {Lettres th{\'e}ologiques},
    Call-Number = {TH: Va 1.05 208},
    Date-Added = {2012-05-04 16:46:23 +0200},
    Date-Modified = {2014-03-30 11:54:26 +0000},
    Editor = {Paul Gallay},
    Keywords = {source},
    Pages = {37-69},
    Publisher = {Les {\'E}ditions du Cerf},
    Series = {Sources chr{\'e}tiennes},
    Shortauthor = {{Gr. Naz.}},
    Shorttitle = {ep. 101},
    Title = {Epistula 101: Ad Cledonium presbyterum contra Apollinarium},
    Usera = {SCh},
    Volume = {208},
    Year = {1974}}
\end{filecontents}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[style=historische-zeitschrift, maxnames=2, hyperref=true, backref=true, backrefstyle=none, backend=bibtex,idemtracker=true]{biblatex}
\bibliography{\jobname}
%
\makeatletter
\renewbibmacro*{footcite}{%
  \global\boolfalse{cbx@loccit}%
  \global\boolfalse{cbx@seenote}% NEW!
  \ifciteseen
    {\iffieldundef{shorthand}
       {\ifthenelse{\ifciteibid\AND\NOT\iffirstonpage}
          {\usebibmacro{footcite:ibid}}
          {\usebibmacro{footcite:note}}}
       {\usebibmacro{footcite:shorthand}}}
       {\iffieldundef{usera}
         {\usebibmacro{footcite:full}}{\printnames{author}%
       \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
       \printfield{title}\isdot%
         {\setunit{\addcomma\space}%
          \usebibmacro{in:}%
          \printfield{usera}%
          \setunit*{\addspace}%
          \printfield[default]{volume}}}}%
     \usebibmacro{footcite:save}}

%

\renewbibmacro*{footcite:note}{%
  \global\booltrue{cbx@seenote}% NEW!
  \ifnameundef{labelname}
    {\printfield{label}}
    {\printnames{labelname}}%
  \ifsingletitle
    {}
    {\setunit*{\addcomma\space}%
     \printfield[title]{labeltitle}}%
  \setunit*{\addspace}%<--- CHANGED
  \printtext{%
    \bibhyperlink{\thefield{entrykey}:%
                  \@nameuse{cbx@first@\thefield{entrykey}}}{%
      \printtext{\bibleftparen}%
      \bibstring{seenote}\addnbspace
      \@nameuse{cbx@note@\thefield{entrykey}}%
      \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
      \bibstring{page}\addnbspace
      \@nameuse{cbx@page@\thefield{entrykey}}}}}

\renewbibmacro*{footcite:save}{%
  \ifundef\@thefnmark
    {\ifundef\@theenmark % endnotes.sty
       {\csgdef{cbx@note@\thefield{entrykey}}{%
          \BibliographyWarning{Missing footnote mark}\textbf{??}}}
       {\global\cslet{cbx@note@\thefield{entrykey}}\@theenmark}}
    {\global\cslet{cbx@note@\thefield{entrykey}}\@thefnmark}%
  \global\cslet{cbx@page@\thefield{entrykey}}\thepage
  \csxdef{cbx@first@\thefield{entrykey}}{\the\value{instcount}}}

% NO PAGES IN INCOLLECTION FOOTNOTES BUT PAGES IN BIBLIOGRAPHY
%
\renewbibmacro*{chapter+pages}{%
  \printfield{chapter}%
  \newunit}
\makeatletter
\renewenvironment{thebibliography}
     {\renewbibmacro*{chapter+pages}{%
  \printfield{chapter}%
  \setunit*{\addcomma\space}%
  \printfield{pages}%
  \newunit}}
\makeatother
%
\begin{document}
\section{First section}
\blindtext\footcite[See][S. 56]{athanasius1998}
\blindtext\footcite[See][S. 22]{evagrius2011}
\pagebreak
\section{Second section}
\blindtext\footcite[Vgl.][S. ]{gregoire1974,gregoire1974/2,gregoire1978,gregoire1978/2,gregorius1862,gregorius1978,gregorius1978/1,gregorius1979/1,gregorius1980,gregorius1980/1,gregorius1981,gregorius1990,gregorius1990/1,gregorius1990/2,gregorius1992}
\blindtext\footcite[See][S. 12]{evagrius2011}
\pagebreak
\section{Third section}
\blindtext\footcite[See][S. 11]{athanasius1998}
\blindtext\footcite[See][S. 12]{evagrius2011}
\pagebreak
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Observe first that the entries *before* the ones where the dash is replaced by the author name do not contain an `editor` field. Once they have an `editor`, everything works as expected. To illustrate this, consider the following example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib} 
@incollection{1,author={a},title={1},editor={b}}
@incollection{2,author={a},title={2},editor={c}}
@incollection{3,author={a},title={3}}
@incollection{4,author={a},title={4},editor={d}}
@book{5,author={a},title={5},editor={d}}
@incollection{6,author={a},title={6},translator={e}}
@incollection{7,author={a},title={7},editor={d}}
\end{filecontents}
\usepackage[style=historische-zeitschrift]{biblatex}
\bibliography{\jobname}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

the result of which is

[image: cropped pdf of example]

There are a few things to be observed:

1. The placement of the dash does not care if the `editor` is the same or not.
2. Neither does it care for the entry type (`@book` vs `@incollection`)
3. If the `editor` field is left blank (missing), the author name is shown in the *next* entry, i.e. no dash.
4. The `translator` field does not act as a substitute for the `editor` field (in this regard).

The reason for this behaviour is a subtlety in the way this [biblatex](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/biblatex) style works.

The treatment of repeated occurrences of the same author in the bibliography by the [historische-zeitschrift](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/historische-zeitschrift) style is determined by the `bibmacro` `author` in [historische-zeitschrift.bbx](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex-contrib/historische-zeitschrift/latex/bbx):

```
\renewbibmacro*{author}{%
  \ifboolexpr{
    test \ifuseauthor
    and
    not test {\ifnameundef{author}}
  }
    {\usebibmacro{bbx:dashcheck}
       {\bibnamedash}
       {\printnames{author}%
     \usebibmacro{bbx:savehash}}}%
    {\global\undef\bbx@lasthash}}
```

This checks if the `author` field should be used and if it is empty. If `author` is not empty, the decision whether to replace the author by a `\bibnamedash` is taken by the `bibmacro` `bbx:dashcheck`, defined in the same file by

```
\newbibmacro*{bbx:dashcheck}[2]{%
  \ifboolexpr{
    test {\iffieldequals{fullhash}{\bbx@lasthash}}
    and
    not test \iffirstonpage
  }
    {#1}
    {#2}}
```

What does this do? It compares the field `fullhash` with `\bbx@lasthash`, which *should* just be the `fullhash` of the last entry. If they are the same, it invokes the first argument (in `author`), i.e. `\bibnamedash`, otherwise the second, i.e. print the name of the author.

If, however, the `author` field is empty (undefined), we're in the case `\global\undef\bbx@lasthash` in the last line of the `author` `bibmacro`, i.e. the value of `\bbx@lasthash` is "reset". In particular, the next entry will definitely not start with a dash as the comparison of `\bbx@lasthash` will always yield false.

Searching the file for occurrences of `\bbx@lasthash`, we see this behaviour also in the `bibmacro` `editor` and -- more subtly still -- in `editorincoll`, a special `bibmacro` for printing the `editor` field in an `@incollection`:

```
\newbibmacro*{editorincoll}{%
  \ifthenelse{\ifuseeditor\AND\NOT\ifnameundef{editor}}
    {\ifthenelse{\iffieldequals{author}{editor}\AND
                 \NOT\iffirstonpage}
       {\bibnamedash}
       {\printnames[upshape]{editor}\addspace
        \usebibmacro{bbx:savehash}}%
     \usebibmacro{editorstrg}%
     \clearname{editor}}
    {\global\undef\bbx@lasthash}}
```

In other words, the last line of this `bibmacro` resets `\bbx@lasthash` if the `editor` field is undefined, stopping the displaying of `\bibdash` in the next entry.

There are several solutions to this problem:

1. The most simple solution is adding an `editor`.
2. Otherwise you can simply remove `\global\undef\bbx@lasthash` from `editorincoll`. This could, however, have undesired consequences, e.g. when dealing with entries without an `author`.
3. The "best" solution is probably to add different checks for each field, i.e. a `dashcheck` for `author` and one for `editor` so that this resetting only happens if indeed both fields are empty.

Comment: First of all thank you for helping and thanks for explaining the problem so thoroughly. I tried to add editors where there is one (sometimes there is none) but the problem seams to be even more deep. If you add two more entries to your MWE you will see what I am talking about: @book{4,author={a},title={4},editor={d}}
@incollection{5,author={a},title={5},editor={d},translator={e}} It seams that the package is not doing books and incollections together for some reason and also if I have translator field than it also makes separate entry.

Comment: @eklisiarh I have updated my answer. Does this make things more clear?

Comment: Yes everything works perfectly now! Thank you for helping!